# Stash snippet problems

Tags: stash

Since upgrading to EE 2.9.0 and Stash 2.5.6 I am having problems with stash snippets.

I am getting results such as %Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q

{exp:stash:set_value name="my_var" type="snippet" value="oof"}

{exp:stash:get name="my_var" type="snippet"}

works fine and prints oof, but

{my_var} prints {my_var}

I have been using the second method extensively through my site in conditionals or simply to display elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Stash variables set to `type="snippet"` can be accessed in the same way as in previous versions of EE. To demonstrate:

```
{embed="inc/snippet_embed"}
{exp:stash:set name="my_snippet" type="snippet"}My snippet{/exp:stash:set}
```

The template **inc/snippet_embed** looks like this:

```
{my_snippet}
<br>
{if my_snippet} My snippet has a value!{/if}
```

Output:

```
My snippet 
<br>
My snippet has a value!
```

Conditionals in EE 2.9 have of course changed which does have some implications when evaluating Stash snippet variables, which you can read about here:

https://gist.github.com/croxton/9d012297096892ca5c10